# optimization for joining many tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables that I'm trying to join. I have added indexes to the tables to increase the speed but is still taking  a long time to join. I suspect this is expected but i was wondering if there is a more efficient way to create a join with multiple tables. I also set the net_read_timeout = to 150 since i was getting a Lost connection error. My query looks like:

```
set net_read_timeout = 150;
ALTER TABLE wspeed2 ADD INDEX (speed,roadtypeID) --For all the tables

SELECT a.month,a.roadTypeID,a.speed,a.pid, a.or, b.pid, b.or, c.pid, c.or, d.pid, d.or,
       e.pid, e.or, f.pid, f.or, g.pid, g.or, h.pid, h.or, i.pid, i.or, j.pid, j.or,
       k.pid, k.or, l.pid, l.or, m.pid, m.or, n.pid, n.or, o.pid, o.or, p.pid, p.or,
       q.pid, q.or, r.pid, r.or, s.pid, s.or, t.pid, t.or, u.pid, u.or, v.pid, v.or
FROM wspeed2 a, wspeed3 b, wspeed20 c, wspeed24 d, wspeed25 e, wspeed26 f, wspeed27 g, wspeed63 h, wspeed65 i, wspeed68 j,
     wspeed69 k, wspeed70 l, wspeed71 m, wspeed72 n, wspeed73 o, wspeed74 p, wspeed75 q, wspeed76 r, wspeed77 s, wspeed78 t, wspeed81 u, wspeed82 v
WHERE a.speed = b.speed and b.speed = c.speed and c.speed = d.speed and d.speed = e.speed and e.speed = f.speed and f.speed = g.speed and g.speed = h.speed
  and h.speed = i.speed and i.speed = j.speed and j.speed = k.speed and k.speed = l.speed and l.speed = m.speed and m.speed = n.speed and n.speed = o.speed
  and o.speed = p.speed and p.speed = q.speed and q.speed = r.speed and r.speed = s.speed and s.speed = t.speed and t.speed = u.speed and u.speed = v.speed
GROUP BY a.speed;
```

Comment: I come from Microsoft background; however, in general, I would use temp table or other staging tables when I have 5+ tables to join.

Comment: This is the prime problem with SQL databases. There's no better way to do this that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the query itself looks simple yet strange, here it is with joins.  Note... Since you had a=b b=c c=d etc... it also means a=r a=s a=t etc... So, instead of having all rely on the alias in front of it, it MIGHT help the engine to have all of the other speed tables as directly joined to the root "a" level alias as I have below.

That said, you are joining 21 different tables, if one or more tables DO NOT have a record for the corresponding speed in the "a" table, they will NOT appear in the result set.  If you want ALL regardless of having a match in the other table, change them all to LEFT JOIN instead.

Now, looking at your "a" table, you are based on a road type and month per speed.  Is the speed column a unique column? I would think it is, but not positive.  If any of the underlying tables being joined to have more than 1 record per same speed value, you will get a Cartesian result and could be choking your query.

Also, you had a group by, but no aggregate function columns such as a SUM(something), count(), avg(), min(), max(), so what is the point of the group by.  You may instead want it ordered by something (preferably something with an index on the "a" table.

```
SELECT 
      a.month, a.roadTypeID, a.speed,
      a.pid, a.or, b.pid, b.or, c.pid, c.or, d.pid, d.or,
      e.pid, e.or, f.pid, f.or, g.pid, g.or, h.pid, h.or, 
      i.pid, i.or, j.pid, j.or, k.pid, k.or, l.pid, l.or, 
      m.pid, m.or, n.pid, n.or, o.pid, o.or, p.pid, p.or,
      q.pid, q.or, r.pid, r.or, s.pid, s.or, t.pid, t.or, 
      u.pid, u.or, v.pid, v.or
   FROM 
      wspeed2 a
         JOIN wspeed3  b on a.speed = b.speed
         JOIN wspeed20 c on a.speed = c.speed
         JOIN wspeed24 d on a.speed = d.speed
         JOIN wspeed25 e on a.speed = e.speed
         JOIN wspeed26 f on a.speed = f.speed
         JOIN wspeed27 g on a.speed = g.speed
         JOIN wspeed63 h on a.speed = h.speed
         JOIN wspeed65 i on a.speed = i.speed
         JOIN wspeed68 j on a.speed = j.speed
         JOIN wspeed69 k on a.speed = k.speed
         JOIN wspeed70 l on a.speed = l.speed
         JOIN wspeed71 m on a.speed = m.speed
         JOIN wspeed72 n on a.speed = n.speed
         JOIN wspeed73 o on a.speed = o.speed
         JOIN wspeed74 p on a.speed = p.speed
         JOIN wspeed75 q on a.speed = q.speed
         JOIN wspeed76 r on a.speed = r.speed
         JOIN wspeed77 s on a.speed = s.speed
         JOIN wspeed78 t on a.speed = t.speed
         JOIN wspeed81 u on a.speed = u.speed
         JOIN wspeed82 v on a.speed = v.speed
```

If this still does not help, maybe adding MySQL keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" might help, such as:

select STRAIGHT_JOIN  [rest of query]

Comment: @Daniel, glad it appeared to work for you.  Would you mind letting me know the performance improvement on the query.  This could be good for others with actual data and similar multiple joins.  Knowing before/after times on this and future queries is good to know.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. After seeing and trying your query structure, i decided to also include pk for all tables that would match all of them. In this case the pk were compose of monthid, roadtype and speed. When doing the join with this structure and the pk in place the query's speed improved from 5 min to a sec.

Answer (score 0):

using inner and left/right join will give you a better performance. Try rewriting the query in this way -

```
select ... from t1
innerjoin t2 on t1.pk=t2.fk
leftjoin t3 on t1.pk=t3.fk
```

Comment: I see no reason why MySQL would not optimize implicit and explicit joins to produce the same execution path.  Why do you think explicit joins would give better performance?

Comment: if 3 table each has 100 rows. in "FROM t1,t2" method it will first create 1000000 rows and then filter.
but in "FROM t1 join t2 ON .." it will create only matching rows.

Comment: @Biswajit, are you sure about this? That's a pretty basic optimization. I find it hard to believe that MySQL is oblivious of it.

Comment: @Biswajit . . . That is not what MySQL does.  Learn how to use `explain`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html.

Answer (score 0):

If the `speed` column is not unique in those tables (and likely it's not; given that you said you added an index with `speed` as a leading column...

If there are multiple rows with the same value of `speed`, in those tables, then your query could be creating an *immense* intermediate set.

Let's do some simple math. If there are two rows in each table that have the same speed value, then the JOIN operations between a and b will create 4 rows for that speed. When we add the join to c, with another two rows, that's a total of 8 rows. When we get all 22 tables joined in, each with two rows, we're at 2^22 or over 4 million rows. And then that whole set of rows, with all the same value for `speed`, needs to be processed in a GROUP BY operation to eliminate duplicates.

(Of course, if any one of the tables doesn't have a row for that same `speed` value, then the query would produce zero rows for that `speed`.)

Personally, I'd ditch the old-school comma syntax for the JOIN operation, and use the JOIN keyword instead. And I'd move the join predicates from the WHERE clause to appropriate ON clause.

I'd also make one of the tables the "driver" for all of the joins, I'd use a reference to the same table in each of the joins. (We know that if `a=b` and `b=c`,  then `a=c`. But I'm not sure about the MySQL optimizer, whether it makes any difference whether we specify `a=b and a=c` in place of `a=b and b=c`.

If there are relatively few number of distinct values of `speed` in each of the tables, but lots of rows with the same value, I'd consider using inline views to get a single row for each speed from each of the tables. MySQL can make use of a suitable index to optimize the GROUP BY operation on each individual table... I'd opt for a covering indexes... e.g.

```
ON wspeed20 (speed, pid, `or`)
ON wspeed24 (speed, pid, `or`)
```

Unfortunately, the derived table (the result of an inline view query) isn't indexed, so the JOIN operations could be expensive (for a lot of rows from each inline view query).

```
SELECT a.month,a.roadTypeID,a.speed,a.pid,a.or, b.pid, b.or, c.pid, c.or, d.pid, d.or,
   e.pid, e.or, f.pid, f.or, g.pid, g.or, h.pid, h.or, i.pid, i.or, j.pid, j.or,
   k.pid, k.or, l.pid, l.or, m.pid, m.or, n.pid, n.or, o.pid, o.or, p.pid, p.or,
   q.pid, q.or, r.pid, r.or, s.pid, s.or, t.pid, t.or, u.pid, u.or, v.pid, v.or

  FROM (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed2  GROUP BY speed) a
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed3  GROUP BY speed) b ON b.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed20 GROUP BY speed) c ON c.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed24 GROUP BY speed) d ON d.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed25 GROUP BY speed) e ON e.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed26 GROUP BY speed) f ON f.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed27 GROUP BY speed) g ON g.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed63 GROUP BY speed) h ON h.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed65 GROUP BY speed) i ON i.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed68 GROUP BY speed) j ON j.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed69 GROUP BY speed) k ON k.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed70 GROUP BY speed) l ON l.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed71 GROUP BY speed) m ON m.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed72 GROUP BY speed) n ON n.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed73 GROUP BY speed) o ON o.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed74 GROUP BY speed) p ON p.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed75 GROUP BY speed) q ON q.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed76 GROUP BY speed) r ON r.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed77 GROUP BY speed) s ON s.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed78 GROUP BY speed) t ON t.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed81 GROUP BY speed) u ON u.speed = a.speed
  JOIN (SELECT speed, pid, `or` FROM wspeed82 GROUP BY speed) v ON v.speed = a.speed
```

That has the potential to cut down on the number of rows that need to be joined (again, if there is a large number of duplicate values for `speed`, and small number of distinct values for `speed`.) But, again, the JOIN operations between the derived tables will not have any available indexes. (At least, not in versions of MySQL up to 5.6.)